# Adjust layout based on framesize when device turned

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, uikit

I'm currently working on the iPad support side of my app. I'm trying to resize the hexagon buttons once the device (or the iPad) is turned. The problem is that the size of the buttons depends on the size of the view that they're inside of. In practice that means that each buttons width and height is equal to `hexagonsView.frame.size / 3.5`. While the buttons do reach the right size, this only happens with a sudden delayed motion after the device gets turned. The titles of the buttons also get either way too big or way too small than they're supposed to be. And weirdly enough, when I call `buttonsSetup()` in `viewDidLoad()`nothing happens at all.

So my question comes down to: how can I resize the buttons with a smooth animation, fix the `viewDidLoad()` bug and also resize the button titles?

The following code setups the buttons:

```
func buttonsSetup() {
    hexButtons.append(contentsOf: [centerHexBtn, upperHexBtn, lowerHexBtn, leftUpHexBtn, leftLowHexBtn, rightUpHexBtn, rightLowHexBtn])

    for hexButton in hexButtons {
        hexButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hexButton.setTitle("A", for: .normal)
        hexButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        if hexButton != centerHexBtn {
            hexButton.color = UIColor.init(named: "Gray")
        }
        hexButton.isEnabled = true
   }
}
```

This is the code that's supposed to resize the buttons once the device is turned:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion: {
        _ in
        self.buttonsSetup()
    })

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    print("View will transition")
}
```

The following code creates the button in the right order:

```
func hexButtonsSetup() {
    for button in hexButtons {
        for constraint in button.constraints {
            button.removeConstraint(constraint)
        }
        button.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    hexagonButtonConfiguration()

    print(hexagonsView.frame.size)

    width = hexagonsView.frame.width
    buttonWidth = hexagonsView.frame.width / 3.5
    buttonHeight = abs(tan(.pi / 3) * buttonWidth / 4 * 2) //actual height of button
    centerButtonsXPosition = width / 2 - buttonWidth / 2
    rightButtonsXPosition = centerButtonsXPosition + buttonWidth / 4 * 3

    distanceRightToCenterBtns = -(buttonWidth / 4) + ((tan(.pi / 3) * (padding / 2)))
    distanceLeftToCenterBtns = -distanceRightToCenterBtns

    hexagonsViewWidthPart1 = buttonWidth * 2 + buttonWidth / 2
    hexagonsViewWidthPart2 = ((tan(.pi / 3) * (padding / 2))) * 2

    let constraints = [

        centerHexBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hexagonsView.centerXAnchor),
        centerHexBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hexagonsView.centerYAnchor),

        upperHexBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hexagonsView.centerXAnchor),
        upperHexBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerHexBtn.topAnchor, constant: buttonWidth - buttonHeight - padding),

        lowerHexBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hexagonsView.centerXAnchor),
        lowerHexBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerHexBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: -(buttonWidth - buttonHeight) + padding),

        rightUpHexBtn.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperHexBtn.rightAnchor, constant: distanceRightToCenterBtns),
        rightUpHexBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperHexBtn.centerYAnchor, constant: -((buttonWidth - buttonHeight) / 2) + (padding / 2)),

        rightLowHexBtn.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerHexBtn.rightAnchor, constant: distanceRightToCenterBtns),
        rightLowHexBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerHexBtn.centerYAnchor, constant: -((buttonWidth - buttonHeight) / 2) + (padding / 2)),

        leftUpHexBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperHexBtn.leftAnchor, constant: distanceLeftToCenterBtns),
        leftUpHexBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperHexBtn.centerYAnchor, constant: -((buttonWidth - buttonHeight) / 2) + (padding / 2)),

        leftLowHexBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerHexBtn.leftAnchor, constant: distanceLeftToCenterBtns),
        leftLowHexBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerHexBtn.centerYAnchor, constant: -((buttonWidth - buttonHeight) / 2) + (padding / 2)),

    ]

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

    adjustButtonFontSize()
}

func hexagonButtonConfiguration() {

    for button in hexButtons {

        hexagonsView.addSubview(button)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hexagonsView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3, constant: 0),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hexagonsView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3, constant: 0),
        ])
    }
}

func adjustButtonFontSize() {

    for button in hexButtons {
        let width = button.frame.width

        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: width / 2.5, weight: .bold)
    }
}
```

It's supposed to look like

[image: this]

But in reality it looks like

[image: this]

Comment: I don't understand your code at all. If you're going to position / size the buttons with constraints, no code is needed to make them change size on rotation. And in `willTransition` you say "This is the code that's supposed to resize the buttons once the device is turned", but you don't resize the buttons, you _create_ the buttons. It all just doesn't hang together.

Comment: The constraints of the buttons are based on the center of the red ```hexagonsView```, which is why when I rotate the device they stay the exact same size even though the ```hexagonsView.frame.size``` changes. The size of the buttons is also not correct in the first place because the program can't read the size of the ```hexagonsView``` in ```viewDidLoad()```. That's why I'm recreating the buttons once the device gets turned

Comment: Okay, I figured out why the size of the buttons were off, thanks to @matt. I set the constraints to be the third of the size of the hexagonsView widthAnchor. Now unfortunately the resizing of the buttons' titles doesn't work.